# how to hide URL in a link button in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and I have a code like this

```
<td class="fit">
  <a href="{{url('addApprovalRequestor/'.$approval_requestor_id.'/'.$user->id)}}" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add
  </a>
</td>
```

**Google Chrome Inspect Element**

[image]

**My View**

[image]
I feel I am not safe using that code, its there's a way how to hide url of code with out using href or form in laravel

Comment: Why do you feel it's not safe to have this link visible?

Comment: @RossWilson its not safe cause its visible when you click inspect element it, that URL is redirect to my routes and my routes call a function in controller, so I wan't to hide it.

Comment: you can obfuscate the url using javascript. but in the end user will see it in browser address bar when who click it.

Comment: It could be obfuscated, but basically if it's usable by the browser, it will have to be visible to the user as well.

Comment: If it's a route that does something that you don't want everyone to be able to do you should lock it down using Auth. That way it doesn't matter if someone see's it as the would need to be authenticated to use it. If standard auth is not enough then you could do a check to make sure the user has permission to go to that url https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Comment: It's pointless to try to hide the url. You need to do server side validation if the url is not meant for everyone. No matter how you obfuscate the url, anyone with a bit of familiarity with web development and browsers will find it in seconds, it still needs to be decoded and requested to work, so can be seen in network tab in developer tools and many other ways.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answer, I think I should use Ross Wilson suggestion, there's no way I can hide url even I disabled right click, or put it in javascript. Some good programmer may able to see it. Thanks again I learn a lot of thing

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is **POST request**

**Route:**

change your route type from **GET** to **POST**

```
Route::post('/addApprovalRequestor','controllerName@methodName');
```

**Blade**

**Use form with post request then url will be hidden**

```
<form action="{{url('/addApprovalRequestor')}}" method="post">
     {{csrf_field()}}
     //save values in hidden input and this form will send it to server
     <input type="hidden" name="approval_requester_id" value="{{$approval_requester_id}}">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$user->id}}">
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
function methodName(Request $request){
   dd($request->request);
   //do what you want here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well i totally agree with @Erkan Özkök and @lofihelsinki ,but still if you want it not to be inspect by chrome inspect you could try disabling the right click button.

Here is the help snippet-

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) { // IE >= 9; other browsers
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else { // IE < 9
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Lorem ipsum...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is on the browser-end can be always exploited.

One way of doing this is pass the value to javascript and make a click event like this =>

```
<a href="#" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="go_to_link(event)">Add
  </a>
```

In javascript =>

```
let link = {{url('addApprovalRequestor/'.$approval_requestor_id.'/'.$user- >id)}};

function show_more_menu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = link;
 }
```

But again there is no way to hide the javascript code. JS-Scripts are running inside your browser.To avoid this also, you can try to compress them, to avoid to easy reading by user. => [here](https://jscompress.com/)

Also you can disable all the bellow actions.

- Right Click
- F12
- Ctrl + Shift + I
- Ctrl + Shift + J
- Ctrl + Shift + C
- Ctrl + U

  `<body oncontextmenu="return false;">`

  ```
   document.onkeydown = function(e) {

    if(event.keyCode == 123) {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)) {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'C'.charCodeAt(0)) {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)) {
       return false;
    }
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)) {
       return false;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: After running jqury url will be visible and even it will take browser to that path

Comment: yep thats is true, like i said you can not completely hide anything on browser side